# react native java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, android-emulator, react-native

I'm trying to make React Native work on an emulator. I'm using Genymotion it works fine, the virtual machines opens without any problem and i have added the SDK to its configuration.

I have the emulator opened and working but when i run react-native run-android i get the following error.

```
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (no error message)

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

I've found out that a possible problem is that i was runnig java 9 and React Native requires java 8 instead (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11755)

So i did the following

I tried changing the version by doing this
**sudo update-java-alternatives --set java-8-oracle**

then checking the version with
**javac -version**

it returns **javac 1.8.0_131**

If i run the app again i still get the error from above

But when i echo $PATH i see that it is still referencing the java 9 folder

```
echo $PATH /home/andrei/.nvm/versions/node/v7.5.0/bin:/home/andrei/bin:/home/andrei/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/db/bin:/home/andrei/Android/Sdk
```

How do I change that or fix this problem?

Comment: If this happens on Ubuntu what does it have to do with Android?

Comment: Well  I'm using an android emulator and it needs to run java . I tagged android due to the fact that i'm trying to build an android dev environment

Comment: Meaning the app crashed on basically an Android device and as such it has nothing to do with ubuntu.

Comment: No it didn't even run on the android it crashed while trying to compile the code i guess

Comment: Compile = IDE which has nothing to do with the OS. If the app crashed while running on Ubuntu OS that would be cause to tag it with ubuntu

Comment: well i solved the problem and it had things to do with Ubuntu because of the way i needed to set the global variables.

Comment: here i removed the ubuntu and android tag and i'll add the answer below

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem

*But when i echo $PATH i see that it is still referencing the java 9 folder*
    echo $PATH /home/andrei/.nvm/versions/node/v7.5.0/bin:/home/andrei/bin:/home/andrei/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/db/bin:/home/andrei/Android/Sdk

in The Home directory open .profile

add the following

**PATH="$PATH:~/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin"**

in this case i'm adding the path to java 8 folder because that is the one i need to use The React-Native according it its specification 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

after setting the PATH you need to make it available inside the terminal you are executing the react-native app by using the following script

**source .~/.profile**

this should get you passed the initial problem with the java 9